# Gradient vanishiment in a simple fashion MNIST classification task

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, classification, mnist

I try to do the fashion MNIST classification with a fully conneted layer and a softmax layer, but it turns out to be that the loss will become a constant after the first epoch:

> Epoch: 0 loss: 2.3611641932884853
>
> Epoch: 1 loss: 2.3611501693725585
>
> Epoch: 2 loss: 2.3611501693725585
>
> Epoch: 3 loss: 2.3611501693725585
>
> Epoch: 4 loss: 2.3611501693725585

This is the code:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
from tensorflow import keras

data = keras.datasets.fashion_mnist
(train_images, train_labels), (test_images, test_labels) = data.load_data()
dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((train_images.reshape(train_images.shape[0], -1), train_labels))

iterator = dataset.make_one_shot_iterator()
X, Y = iterator.get_next()
X = tf.reshape(X, [1, 784])
X = tf.cast(X, tf.float32)
Y = tf.one_hot(Y, depth=10)
 
W = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([784, 10])) 
b = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([10])) 
y_pre = tf.nn.softmax(tf.matmul(X, W) + b)

cross_entropy_loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits_v2(labels=Y, logits=y_pre) ) 
optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.5).minimize(cross_entropy_loss)

writer = tf.summary.FileWriter('./graphs/linear_reg', tf.get_default_graph())
with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    for epoch_num in range(100):
        sess.run(iterator.make_initializer(dataset))
        loss = 0
        try:
            while True:
                _, l = sess.run([optimizer, cross_entropy_loss])
                loss += l
        except tf.errors.OutOfRangeError:
            pass
        print("Epoch:",epoch_num, "loss:", loss/60000) #训练集一共有60000张图片
writer.close()
```

Answer (score 2):

You're initializing your weights variable to zeros, so the optimizer is unable to compute gradients. Also, `0.5` is extremely high for a gradient descent learning rate.

Try initializing your weights variable randomly:

```
W = tf.get_variable("W", shape=[784, 10], initializer=tf.random_uniform_initializer())
b = tf.get_variable("b", shape=[10], initializer=tf.zeros_initializer())
```

And set your learning rate to something on the order of `0.0005` instead.

There are also [other initializers](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_guides/python/state_ops#Sharing_Variables) that you might prefer instead.

The [tutorial video for Tensorboard](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/summaries_and_tensorboard) actually covers the exact scenario of zero weight initialization. You are already writing a summary in your code, it might be a good idea to review that video to see how to use it to help debugging.

Comment: Thank you very much! It's really a big deal for a beginner like me.